# Equations don't show up in the output

Tags: align, output

I'm working on my final year project using LaTeX. I'm facing a right now where part of my writing doesn't show up on my PDF output. The other writing in this section is ok, but this particular equation suing the command align doesn't show up. This is my command:

The model can be simplified as below

```
\begin{align}
(\frac{d}{dt})(\frac{S_{h}}{N_{h}})&=\mu_{h}-\frac{\beta_{h}b}{{N_{h}}^2}-\frac{\mu_{h}S_{h}}{N_{h}}\\
&=\mu_{h}(1-\frac{S_{h}{N_{h}})-\frac{b\beta_{h}A}{\mu_{v}N_{h}}(\frac{S_{h}}{N_{h}})(\frac{I_{v}}{\frac{A}{\mu_{v}}})\\
(\frac{d}{dt})(\frac{I_{h}}{N_{h}})&=\frac{\beta_{h}b}{{N_{h}}^2}I_{v}S_{h}-\frac{(\mu_{h}\gamma_{h})I_{h}}{N_{h}}\\
&=\frac{b\beta_{h}A}{\mu_{v}N_{h}}(\frac{S_{h}}{N_{h}})(\frac{I_{v}}{A/\mu_{v}})-(\gamma_{h}+\mu_{h})\frac{I_{h}}{N_{h}}\\
(\frac{d}{dt})(\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}})&=\frac{\beta_{v}b}{N_{h}N_{v}}I_{h}S_{v}-\frac{\mu_{v}I_{v}}{N_{v}}\\
&=\frac{\beta_{v}bI_{h}}{N_{h}N_{v}}(\frac{A}{\mu_{v}}-I_{v})-\mu_{v}\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}}\\
&=\frac{\beta{v}bI_{h}A}{N_{h}N_{v}\mu_{v}}-\frac{\beta_{v}bI_{h}I_{v}}{N_{h}N_{v}}-\mu_{v}\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}}\\
&=\beta_{v}b(\frac{A}{N_{v}\mu_{v}}-\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}})\frac{I_{h}}{N_{h}}-\mu_{v}\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}}\\
&=\beta_{v}b(1-\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}})\frac{I_{h}}{N_{h}}-\mu_{v}\frac{I_{v}}{N_{v}}\
\end{align}
```

But the output doesn't show the `align` instruction. Instead, I got this:

[image]

As you can see the output resumes to my next section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's difficult to say from this fragment of , but I guess that the issue is that `align` does not break across pages, unless `\allowdisplaybreaks` is used.

Comment: Tq for your reply Mr Hupfer. Tried adding \allowdisplaybreaks before my align command. But the output is still the same as before.

Comment: @Reyaz Please, check you get no error message from the LaTeX run.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Found the problem. Helped a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op found and solved the problem; noted in comments.